# How to convert Json string with escape characters to json in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting the following json as a reponse of a rest call. I am unable to parse it. Replacing `"\"` with `""` doesn't work as the string contains many escape characters like `"\n"`.

`"[{\"message_id\":50870,\"message\":\"4d074d54-6e08-a140-fb7a-ee1300b01fbf.png\"},
{\"message_id\":50823,\"message\":\"1\\n2\\n3\\n4\\n5\\n6\"},{\"message_id\":50341,\"message\":\"I am getting a \\\"Server Error\\\" }]"`

I have tried JsonTokener, UrlDecoder, but nothing seems to work. 
I have also tried using
    JsonString.replace ("\\"", "\"");
This works but is there a better way for conversion

Comment: Are you *certain* the string really, really has those backslashes in, rather than them being shown to use in the debugger? If so, you could parse that string as a JSON string, and then parse the *result* as a JSON object.

Comment: what have you done so far for parsing? please post code

Comment: is the response creates manually ? if so, why you are not using `JSONArray` to build your array?

Comment: yes the string really has those backslashes @JonSkeet

Comment: @KritiSharma Did you found any bettor way to solve this?

Comment: @Dharmraj..No :-(

Answer (score -2):

```
JSONSerialiser serialiser = new JSONSerialiser();
String jsonOutput= serialiser.include("id","message").exclude("*").serialize(javaobject);

JSONObject jObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject(jsonOutput);
```